# C# - How To Update Nested Values in JSON body using FormUrlEncodedContent?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

I need to do a basic update to a JSON package using **FormUrlEncodedContent**

At the moment, I can only assign values at parent level.

For example, here's the JSON package that will be sent through the API.

```
[
    {
        "id": 29519,
        "first_name": "xxxx",
        "last_name": "xxx",
        "billing": {
            "address_1": "xxxx",
            "address_2": "xxxx"
        }
   }
]
```

At the moment, I can only update the **first_name** and **last_name** values using the following code:

```
var UpdateCustomerAPI = "https://example.com/api/";
var UpdateCustomer_JSON = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
   new KeyValuePair<string,string>("first_name", CustomerFirstName.Text),
   new KeyValuePair<string,string>("last_name", CustomerLastName.Text)
});
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = httpClient.PutAsync(UpdateCustomerAPI, UpdateCustomer_JSON);
```

How do I update the values in **billing:address_1** and **billing:address_2** using the **FormUrlEncodedContent**?

Comment: your code should show a failed attempt to do billing address request.  not just code that works - code that (re)produces your issue.  (for, at the moment I don't know what the control\variable name you're using for customer billing address1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent?view=netcore-3.1

> A container for name/value tuples encoded using application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME type.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded: the keys and values are encoded in key-value tuples separated by '&', with a '=' between the key and the value.

You are not putting a json file to your server. If you want to use it, then you should do something like:

```
var UpdateCustomer_JSON = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
   new KeyValuePair<string,string>("billing_address_1", CustomerBillingAddress.Text),
});
```

If you want to post a json file, then you should use `application/json` mine type and use something like this:

```
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerData);
```

Comment: hmm.. yea.. this is generally correct.. but it ultimately depends on how the api server handles the form urlencoded data.  you can absolute post\put `&billing=<json>` where `json` is urlencoded `{ address_1=90210 }`, but if that data isn't deserialized by the server then it's just a string.

Comment: So do all the json conversions to create the json, just to add it as a parameter, and then deserialize only the specific parameter. Based on the example given, I don't think that's the ask.

Comment: Thanks @Brett-Caswell however with this API - (Woocommerce) - it can only accept PUT and expects a JSON body to update the customer details, can't pass any parameters via the API url.

Comment: I also tried "new KeyValuePair<string,string>("billing_address_1", CustomerBillingAddress.Text)" but doesn't seem to work. May have to try a different approach.

Comment: You do. Create a customer object with an address object and serialize to json as demonstrated in the answer. Then, PUT the serialized body.

Comment: @Khoa based on your last comment, and question, I think you may not understand what your own code is currently doing.. you aren't currently posting JSON in any respect. you are basically doing PUT to a url `www.example.com` with `first_name=First&last_name=Last` in the body and `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the header.

Comment: @Khoa here, I uploaded some quick Fiddler screenshots for your review https://imgur.com/a/unck6GC .. and, I didn't include Athanasios's suggested add\define using `application/json` as the content-type (it should probably be done\test).  but given the formurlencoded criteria, json body.. it's hard to tell what the actual requirements are without reviewing the documentation

Comment: Thanks heaps @BrettCaswell for setting that up. I tested out your code outlined in the "TestPutStringAsync" function and it's working. Would you mind pasting your solution in the answer and will tick it off. Cheers.